# Convert ASP.NET MVC App to Web Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How would I go about using the MVC framework in the ASP.NET standard web site model, instead of the web *application* model?

Comment: I don't think that is possible, at least not the entire framework with all the functionality that is built into it. Why do you want to?

Comment: @Tomas, I am used to developing and deploying from the web site model, and I enjoy the on-demand compilation and easy updating of sites built with that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/08/15/How-To-Use-ASPNET-MVC-in-Website-rather-than-Web-Application-Project.aspx) is explained how.

Comment: That's pretty obsolete - MVC has released in one more preview, one beta, two release candidates and the final version since...

Comment: However, the steps he describes don't seem to be out of the realm of possibility.  It might be interesting to try it...

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but I don't think MVC has changed _that_ much since Preview 4 that this isn't possible anymore.
Although I pretty sure that there is no tooling for MVC in Visual Studio after the conversion.